determine the Galois group

Let $p$ be a odd prime,$\zeta_n=e^{2\pi i/p}\in \mathbb{C},E=Q(\zeta_n,\sqrt[p]{2})\subseteq\mathbb{C}$
let
$$\ E_0=E\bigcap\mathbb{R},
$$
determine
$\ Gal(E/E_0)$.

I guess $Gal(E/E_0)\cong(\mathbb{Z}_2,+)$, but I am not sure it is true. Is there someone prove it rigorously?

Obviously $\sqrt[p]{2}\in E_0$, therefore $E=E_0(\zeta_n)$.
As $\zeta_n$ satisfies $x^2-\eta x + 1 = 0$ where $\eta=\zeta_n+\overline{\zeta_n} = \zeta_n + \frac{1}{\zeta_n}\in E_0$, so $[E:E_0]\le 2$.
But $p\ge 3$, therefore $\zeta_n$ is not real, hence $E\not=E_0, [E:E_0]\ge 2$.
Combined, $[E:E_0]=2$. An extension of degree $2$ must be normal, and $E/E_0$ is separable since we are in the world of characteristic $0$, hence Galois. Finally any group of order $2$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.

Thank you for your precise answer!
